# Implementing a Web Api Controller - why does use of IDisposable interfere with routing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dispose

I have implemented a Web Api class as such:

```
public class ControllerCore : ApiController 
{
    ...do some basic things...
}
```

And then in a derived class have:

```
public class LoginController : ControllerCore
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
       // Get login status
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]LoginParams login)
    {
       // Do actual log in
    }
 }
```

This all works fine.  But I would *like* to make the ControllerCore disposable so I can create and clean up a managed object that contains an open database connection:

```
public class ControllerCore : ApiController, IDisposable
{
    protected DataAccess DAL;
    private bool isDalDisposed;

    public ControllerCore()
        : base()
    {
        DAL = new DataAccess();  // opens a connection that will have to be cleaned up
        isDalDisposed = false;
    }

    public new void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!isDalDisposed)
        {
            isDalDisposed = true;
            if (disposing)
                DAL.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    ...other code here...
}
```

The problem is that while the "Get" on the LoginController still works but the "Post" never gets called - the route doesn't seem to work.  Since the only difference is that the Post has arguments, I am wondering if somehow the Disposable modification is messing up the conversion from JSON to the LoginParams object.

Any help would be *greatly* appreciated!

Comment: Since ApiController already implements IDisposbale interface, you subclasses can just override the base's Dispose method...why do you want to implement IDisposable interface again? Just FYI...you can refer to the guidance on class inheritance and dispose behavior here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that the response from the Web API is: Multiple actions were found that match the request.

It is the Web API routing that gets messed up because your controller has two methods that matches the Post request.
The default is that any public method on your API controller that isn't matched by any of the rules for selecting action methods is considered to be a Post method.
You can find more information on the subject [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection).

To fix your problem just add [NonAction] attribute to your Dispose method so Web API will ignore it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the Answer!  It honestly makes a lot of sense when you put it that way but I am still getting used to the route-matching rules and hadn't thought that "Dispose" could be taken as an Action.

Comment: You should never hide the public Dispose method. The base class already has all the necessary logic there. All your cleanup logic should be in the overridden protected Dispose method. And the controller already implements the IDisposable interface.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `System.Web.Http.ApiController` already implements IDisposable:

So, if your controller holds a database connection, do the following:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    private Model1Container _model1 = new Model1Container();

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_model1 != null)
            {
                _model1.Dispose();
            }
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```